# Typescript classes deserialized json

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have 2 classes that represent a Tree structure as follows:

```
class Node {
        private _id: string;
        name: string;
        parent?: Node;
        children: Node[];
}

class Tree {
    root: Node;
    treeMap: Map<string, Node>;
}
```

I am writing a api `GET /tree` which should return tree json in the following manner:

```
[
    {
        "1": {
            "name": "root",
            "children": [
                {
                    "2": {
                        "name": "fish",
                        "children": [] // empty children
                    }
                },
                {
                    "3": {
                        "name": "bird",
                        "children": [ ...<any children>... ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

when I do `ctx.body = tree` this is what the api returns:

```
{
    "root": {
        "_id": "1",
        "name": "root",
        "children": [
            {
                "_id": "2",
                "name": "fish",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "_id": "3",
                "name": "bird",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    "treeNodeMap": {}
}
```

What would be the right way to convert it to the desired json format?

Comment: Why should `/tree` respond with an array?

Comment: while currently there is just one tree instance, there is a possibility to have more hence an array. Keeping that in mind I can see how it makes it confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your classes implement [toJSON()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior) to produce the data structure you want.

```ts
// Define the data structure
interface SerialisedNode {
  [id: string]: {
    name: string;
    children: SerialisedNode[]
  }
}

class Node {
  private _id: string;
  name: string;
  parent?: Node;
  children: Node[];

  toJSON(): SerialisedNode {
    return {
      [ this._id ]: {
        name: this.name,
        children: this.children.map(node => node.toJSON())
      }
    }
  }
}

class Tree {
  root: Node;
  treeMap: Map<string, Node>;

  toJSON(): SerialisedNode {
    return this.root.toJSON();
  }
}
```

When your `Tree` (or any `Node`) is stringified as JSON, the transform will kick in and deliver the alternate data structure.

[TypeScript Playground Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMrWHANsAXhAEwDkB7AlAbwChlkBtYAgLmQGcwpQBzAXRetq0QcALYQW7TiC4BuGoIQALYFgJQIIFuk7Y8hUuTo95AXypmqCLHFatkRA5XkAHTgDc4kZAH1GEjtxyQqLibAHSQcjOcOrgAPwsjpFKKmoaiY5GcvIIJCCSAK4IYCRQABR+YVJcADTIwmL+1XUpqrEZZBBGyAC89DwAlMgCgmDKrAB0vgS9yIyRtGPAkw0ofasLyEuTrWkgs7uxkRaLJABSqADyRGUDWhi6+MSdw-K06mAFUPsjgvRb4ymjGQfFefz+qxY2wmqxqb3Bh3SAOWE0RIAmIjgzjKIBePQAfPVOhMShdrrcBvDaGY-jTkGYLFYbHYACrqJzvEgkMAdcjZWi5fIcIolcpQLk8+yOIYUZGTcXc2YKsAyelUeSkq43O5oB44J6OMGCD5ffbQ5Uk85a27HczqwXsZDK2YgCAAdylnTKACIAIzeure5UB+jyV0ehxe70AJhD3pgy0U3oGcKE7s95B9AGY4wAjYBQAjJqiDbIOsBbdku9NsiAQMrKgZlvKsEhYCATLAkLhlMlECaSbjAGAATzKHDrdRABSwWDq0YGTaAA)